# phantomjs: How to use npm modules in phantomjs?

Tags: npm, phantomjs

Could you use npm modules by using require() in phantomJS? It seems to be able to load javascript files so maybe this is possible?

Comment: Have you tried doing exactly what you've said? Perhaps you would be pleasantly surprised.

Comment: can I find an example? it's not loading the npm module for me.

Comment: I just tried importing npm modules using `require`, can you give me a code sample of what you'be tried?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is entirely depends on the **nodejs** module. It won't work if **nodejs** module requires some support via native function interface.(npm modules like http, socket.io, will not work on phantomjs, because it dependents on native interfaces)

Pure JavaScript **nodejs** modules should work on **phantomjs** too.

Comment: For example, chalk is not usable because it depends on process module.

Comment: Can you provide an example, properly how to inject node module into phantomjs? Answer is obvious by how to make it work, require or injectjs?

Answer (score 4):

fyi, phantomjs has an aproximation of commonjs.

you can not use amd modules in phantomjs, and I do not know of any amd loader (like requirejs) that works in phantomjs

***Update (2015)***: I have been using commonjs modules in PhantomJs 1.x and 2.x, they work well with one caveat:  you can not use source-mapping (at the bottom of the file, looks like `//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map`) as it will cause the PhantomJs module loader to fail.  Otherwise, commonjs modules will load normally.

Comment: The sourceMappingUrl comment was my undoing too. Thanks for the tip!